# How to pass image to python script using flask?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have a website (managed with python-flask) with images on canvas and i would like to pass the content of those canvas to another python script as images.

The other python script is using openCV in order to perform face detection.

I know i could upload the image on my server and then read the file on my opencv application but i would like not to save any data on my server.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: You don't have to save them, you can use `file.read()` method on the uploaded file object in flask and send that to OpenCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You anyway should upload file to the server, because you need to transfer user's data to your server application.

But instead of saving it as a regular file, you could use someting like [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile)

In other words, you'll have workflow like this:

1. Send image with POST to the server;
2. Read file from POST request with flask;
3. Write it to SpooledTemporaryFile and receive a file-like object;
4. Use that file-like object for OpenCV